# How to change header logo in specific page in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have following react code.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-active-class-metzq)

What I would like is to when I click on header logo, it should change on another logo (let's call that component A). But in other cases when I click on "home", "about" or "contact" it should change on component B.

I write

```
  <img src={useLocation().pathname == "/" ? { A } : { B }} alt="" />
```

but it not show any image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is minor change
instead of

```
<img src={useLocation().pathname == "/" ? { A } : { B }} alt="" />
```

change to this

```
<img src={useLocation().pathname == "/" ? A : B} alt="" />
```